# Is OctoberCMS MIT licensed?

Tags: octobercms

---

If I go to the OctoberCMS GitHub repo, it says that

> https://github.com/octobercms/october
>   The OctoberCMS platform is open-sourced software licensed under the MIT license.

However, the website https://github.com/octobercms/october#license says something different.

I would like to modify OctoberCMS source code and offer it as my own product.  Can I do this or not?

Comment: Where does "the website" say something different? Under https://github.com/octobercms/october#license it clearly states: "*The OctoberCMS platform is open-sourced software licensed under the MIT license*".

Answer (score 2):

If you download the source code from https://github.com/octobercms/october then
Please take care of the below points.

1. Entire source code folder is governed by MIT license.
2. syntaxhighlighter: 
   (root\gitHub\octobermaster\modules\system\assets\vendor\syntaxhighlighter)
    The above folder file has attached with the 2 license file i.e MIT and LGPL.

   If you are using any of the file(s) from this folder then please opt for the MIT license. Else if you opt for the LGPL license then dynamically link the folder file(s) with your application.
3. Some of the *.js file are dual licensed under MIT/GPL. If you are using any of the file(s) in your application then please opt for the MIT license.

Conclusion:
OctoberCMS is a open source component and licensed under MIT license. 
It's free to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the application. There is no restrictions on anything.

Please add the copyright and MIT license to the portion/file with or without modification of the OctoberCMS that you are going to add in your application.

Answer (score 0):

The OctoberCMS platform is open-sourced software licensed under the MIT license.

Answer (score 0):

I think - Yes :) 
They have a License file into the repository

https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: It is MIT Licensed, yes. The topbar cleary indicates that. You may reword and extend your answer a bit.

Comment: Hi @chade_ , Thanks. I'm new at the stackoverflow, how I can change my answer?

Comment: With using the [edit](link). you seed it the end of each post, righ to the share link, when you click that, you'll be taken to a page where you can edit your post.